# Выполнить строку как функцию без ручного load каждый раз

Tags: lua

Иногда удобно написать `x()`, когда `x` -- строка, вместо явного `assert(loadstring(x))()` каждый раз. Как такой процесс можно автоматизировать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Самое простое решение:

```
local strtab = getmetatable(''); -- Операция с метатаблицей для всех строк
local strcalls = setmetatable({}, {__mode = 'v'}); -- Кэшировать результаты loadstring в слабую таблицу
if strtab == nil then
    return error("I can't set default table for strings, sorry.", 2) -- И такое бывает!
end;

strtab.__call = function(str, ...) -- в момент x()
    local func;
    if strcalls[str] ~= nil then -- Если функция есть в кэше...
        func = strcalls[str]; -- ...взять её оттуда...
    else -- ...иначе...
        func = assert(loadstring(str)); -- ...скомпилировать её...
        strcalls[str] = func -- ...записать компилированый вариант в кэш...
    end
    return func(...) -- ...и выполнить!
end;
strtab = nil
return strcalls -- Для доступа в внутренней таблице, не обязательно ловить
```

Последняя строка позволяет получить доступ к кэшу при необходимости (обычно, этого не надо).

Примечание: в `pcall()` аргументом тоже теперь можно будет строку писать, что довольно удобно. Например:

```
require 'strcall'
print(pcall 'string.dump("a")') --> false   [string "string.dump("a")"]:1: bad argument #1 to 'dump' (function expected, got string)
```